# Docusign adds receiver of a copy of an envelope as signer

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create an envelope with one signer and multiple copy recipients. I created two roles in my template: "signer" (Needs to Sign) and "cc" (Receives a Copy). Using the DocuSign API endpoint to create envelope I send the following payload:

```
{
"templateId": "my template id here",
"status": "sent",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "signersemail@mydomain.com",
        "roleName": "signer",
        "name": "Main signer",
        "tabs": {}
    },
    {
        "email": "petya@mydomain.com",
        "roleName": "cc",
        "name": "Petya"
    },
    {
        "email": "vasya@mydomain.com",
        "roleName": "cc",
        "name": "Vasya"
    }
]
}
```

After sending this request, I use the get envelope endpoint and see that two recipients are signers and one is carbon copy receiver:

```
   "recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "Vasya",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "vasya@mydomain.com",
            "recipientId": "3",
            "recipientIdGuid": "e30e2401-7b18-45d7-89f5-9f10d28e43cb",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "3abe9923-9b9d-49b1-85a5-ac9e6e8fc545",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "cc",
            "status": "sent",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "sentDateTime": "2023-03-30T14:38:41.0700000Z",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        },
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "Main signer",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "signersemail@mydomain.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "d015e195-9c5e-4c75-bc32-c7105f97616b",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "aab4f1d2-7540-4bdd-8d37-577adf02b0e6",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "signer",
            "status": "sent",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "sentDateTime": "2023-03-30T14:38:41.6170000Z",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [
        {
            "name": "Petya",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "petya@mydomain.com",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "recipientIdGuid": "b2372f1e-a46c-4dcf-bb59-0742eba8fd05",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "6b932240-911d-4f04-a15d-95eb7bd290f8",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "cc",
            "status": "created",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "templateRequired": "false",
            "recipientType": "carboncopy"
        }
    ],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "seals": [],
    "witnesses": [],
    "notaries": [],
    "recipientCount": "3",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
},
```

Why did the recipient Vasya become a signer?

Answer (score 0):

To include another person in the cc list, you need to add another recipient as a CarbonCopy to your template definition. If your template only has two placeholder recipients, the third person you add when you send the envelope will default to a signer. The "roleName" value does not define recipient type since users can enter anything for this value, you need to make that association in the template definition.

Comment: It's very non-obvious. So, I have to know the number of сс recipients in advance?